# Django struggling to make migrations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently learning django and doing the tutorial from Django Rest Framework.

The problem is the following. I have the following tree:

```
.
./tutorial
./tutorial/manage.py
./tutorial/tutorial
./tutorial/tutorial/__init__.py
./tutorial/tutorial/__init__.pyc
./tutorial/tutorial/settings.py
./tutorial/tutorial/settings.pyc
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/__init__.py
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/__init__.pyc
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/admin.py
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/apps.py
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/apps.pyc
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/migrations
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/migrations/__init__.py
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/models.py
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/tests.py
./tutorial/tutorial/snippets/views.py
./tutorial/tutorial/urls.py
./tutorial/tutorial/wsgi.py
```

I added dependencies in settings.py by adding

```
'rest_framework',
'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',
```

in INSTALLED_APPS.

The problem is that when I do `ElbattoresMacbook:tutorial elbattore$ python manage.py makemigrations snippets`. I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 142, in create
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named snippets
```

What's wrong with what I do?? I'm strictly following http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

But it doesn't work...

Thanks guys

Comment: Did you create the snippets app using "python manage.py startapp snippets" command? The snippets folder should be at the same level than manage.py file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did this step twice:

```
cd tutorial
```

... and ended up inside `./tutorial/tutorial` instead of `./tutorial`.

You can fix that either by moving `snippets` one folder-level lower or change installed app to `tutorial.snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig`. I suggest moving the folder one level lower. Your structure should look like this:

```
./tutorial
-/tutorial/tutorial     <-- Project settings folder
./tutorial/snippets     <-- App folder
```